# How can I create a post, i have two mongoose models ref'ing each other

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, model

Basically I wanna create a Post that has its author to the users name, the one who created it. I also want the Post to be pushed into the array of posts, which the user model has, that is ref'ing to "Post".

I have been googling and watching youtube videos but still i do not understand how i would go about to do this, also i read about populate, but i wanna create a new post and have the author to be the users name, also i want the post to be pushed into the array of posts that the user has.

How would I go about doing this ?

This is the post create controller

```
exports.postCreatePost = (req, res, ) => {

    const {
        title,
        description,
        context
    } = req.body;

    const post = new Post({
        title,
        description,
        context,
        author: 
    })

}
```

This is the model.js

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema,
        bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");


        const postSchema = new Schema({
            title: String,
            description: String,
            context: String,
            author: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "User"
            }
        });

        const userSchema = new Schema({
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },

            email: {
                type: String,
                required: true,
            },

            password: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },

            posts: [{
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Post"
            }]
        });


        userSchema.pre("save", async function save(next) {
            const user = this;
            if (!user.isModified("password")) return next();
            const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10);
            user.password = hashedPassword;
            next();
        });

const Post = mongoose.model("Post", postSchema);
const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
const userId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Either let client send you username/id and get it from req.body or when you are authenticating user simply pass the reference to the user to the body of request.

For example when client gives you id/username you can do something like this

```
const post = new Post({
    title,
    description,
    context,
    author: req.body.username or req.body.id
})
```

If you want to push use this

```
await findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.id}, {
        "$push":
        {
            "posts": post._id
        }
    })
```

Comment: but where does req.body.username come from, plus i do not wanna push it like that, since it is an array of posts i wanna push it differently, and is req.body.id the id of the user, am i not suppose to use userId ?

Comment: it never hurts to try things doe gonna try stuffs lawl

Comment: Either from the client request body or if you have authentication you can pass User data to request body. I'm not sure how you want to push it, you didn't specify. That way you can reference the post and receive it's data by populate.

Comment: i tried it differently:     const {
        title,
        description,
        context
    } = req.body;

    const post = new Post({
        title,
        description,
        context,
        author: req.user
    });
    product.save()
    .then(result => {
        result.author.posts.push(post[0]);
        console.log("created post");
        res.redirect("/posts");
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })

Comment: you can review that, i tried formatting it but didnt work, and tell me how i would continue with this